# How to get enum values while both cases are true in c#

Tags: c#, enums

I have a enum which contains 3 values for 3 checkboxes:

```
public enum Str
{
    Test = 1,
    Exam = 2,
    Mark = 4
}
```

Imagine these are checkboxes. If I select any of them it works fine but when I select multiple checkboxes are selected, Enum values are getting added.

When I check Test and Mark Enum value is `5` and when I select Test and Exam the result is `3`
I even tried Type casting

```
 string sVal = "checkbox Value";
 bool ival = int.TryParse(sValue,out iVal);
 if(iVal)
 {
   int iValue = int.Parse(sValue)
    str s = (str)iValue;
 }
```

again "s" returns the added value not the enum types how to solve this?

Comment: When you define the enum, just attribute it with [Flags](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1030091/284240)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **do** want the value to be the addition of 1 and 4.
Here's how to test your values:

```
public enum Str
{
    Test = 1,
    Exam = 2,
    Mark = 4
}

private static void Main()
{
    Str test = (Str)5;  // Same as  test = Str.Test | Str.Mark;

    if ((test & Str.Test) == Str.Test)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Test");
    }

    if ((test & Str.Exam) == Str.Exam)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exam");
    }

    if ((test & Str.Mark) == Str.Mark)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Mark");
    }

    Console.Read();
}
```

The `Flag` attribute should be used, so other people know your enum should be used with bitwise operations. But this attribute itself does nothing (expect maybe modifying the `.ToString()` result).

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're are looking for is the Flags attribute: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx

Comment: if i am getting Value is '5' how can i get the enum names

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do several things for this to work for you.

1. Set the `[Flags]` attribute on the enum. It will work without it, but it's a nice thing to have, even if just for documentation purposes.

   ```
   [Flags]
   public enum Str
   {
     None = 0
     Test = 1,
     Exam = 2,
     Mark = 4
   }
   ```
2. To set the Enum you'll need to loop the selected checkboxes and set the values, something along the lines of:

   ```
   Str value = Str.None;
   if (chkTest.Checked)
      value = value | Str.Test;
   if (chkExam.Checked)
      value = value | Str.Exam;
   if (chkMark.Checked)
      value = value | Str.Mark;
   ```

   After this runs, if, lets say, Test and exam are checked, the value will be:

   ```
   (int) value       =>  3
   value.ToString()  => "Str.Test|Str.Exam".
   ```
3. To check if a enum value has a specific flag, you could do:

   ```
   Str value = ....
   if (value.HasFlag(Str.Test))
      // it has test selected 
   else
      // it does not have test selected
   ```

   or you could do

   ```
   Str value = ....
   if (value & Str.Test == Str.Test)
      // it has test selected 
   else
      // it does not have test selected
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
         if((EnumVal & Str.Exam) ==Str.Exam)|| EnumVal == Str.Exam)
```

Solved.....

Answer (score 0):

You may not use Flags attribute. But your enum values should be pow of 2.

Int values of your enums:

```
var values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Str)).Cast<int>().Where(x => (x & iVal) != 0).ToList()
```

Then:

```
values.Select(x => list[(int)Math.Log(x, 2)])
```

`list` is list of your checkboxes which you can iterate and set checked.

```
var list = new List<CheckBox>
           {
               firstCheckBox,
               secondCheckBox,
               thirdCheckBox,
           };
```