# how to add multiple enum values with pipe based on conditions?

Tags: c#, enums

I was trying to add multiple enum values to a variable based on conditions. For example, I have something like this:

```
SharedAccessBlobPermissions t = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Write | SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read;
```

if user has chosen other available enum values on the UI, i want to add them was well. But it looks like we can only write it on one line and can't add multiple values later on.

Any idea how can I achieve this?

[Update]
Based on the answers, this is what I wrote

```
var t= new SharedAccessBlobPermissions();
        if (isAllowRead)
        {
            t = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read;
        }
        if (isAllowWrite)
        {
            t |= SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Write;
        }
```

Comment: Just add more values, concatenate them by `|`, you can break it to multilines until you end all by a `;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If SharedAccessBlobPermissions has been declared with [Flags] attribute
you can do some set arithemtics. If initially

```
  SharedAccessBlobPermissions t = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Write | SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read;
```

Addtion:

```
  // Add SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Delete and SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Clear 
  t |= SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Delete | SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Clear;
```

Subtraction:

```
  // Remove SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Delete
  t = (t | SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Delete) ^ SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Delete;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can keep adding more values to the bitmask by bitwise-oring them with the current value:

```
t |= SharedAccessBlobPermissions.AnotherOption
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [Flags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx) attribute.
See the following example:

```
[Flags]
enum DaysOfWeek
{
   Sunday = 1,
   Monday = 2,
   Tuesday = 4,
   Wednesday = 8,
   Thursday = 16,
   Friday = 32,
   Saturday = 64
}

public void RunOnDays(DaysOfWeek days)
{
   bool isTuesdaySet = (days & DaysOfWeek.Tuesday) == DaysOfWeek.Tuesday;

   if (isTuesdaySet)
      //...
   // Do your work here..
}

public void CallMethodWithTuesdayAndThursday()
{
    this.RunOnDays(DaysOfWeek.Tuesday | DaysOfWeek.Thursday);
}
```

I suggest you to read the following [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030090/how-do-you-pass-multiple-enum-values-in-c)

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447/what-does-the-flags-enum-attribute-mean-in-c/8480#8480) is another useful answer