# Pass multiple enum to methods and get their values

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, enums

Please consider this code:

```
public enum Status
{
    S1 = 1,
    S2 = 2,
    S3 = 3,
    S4 = 4
}
```

I know I can pass multiple enum using `|` oerator to a method:

```
public void DoWork(Status S)
{
}
...
DoWork(Status.S1 | Status.S2);
```

Now In DoWork Method I want to get values of passed enums. For Example In above code I want to get `{1, 2}`. How I cas do this? 
thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you pass multiple enum values in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030090/how-do-you-pass-multiple-enum-values-in-c)

Comment: You should use powers of two for the values (1, 2, 4, 8...), and mark the `Status` enum with the `[Flags]` attribute.

Comment: @Sharped In that question I haven't seen a response that explains how to transform a (flag) Enum to an array/list of enum values

Comment: @Sharped : No this isnot duplicate of that topic. I want to get enums values

Comment: possible duplicate of [Iterate over values in Flags Enum?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4171140/iterate-over-values-in-flags-enum)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are few steps to follow to get flagged enum  :

1. Use `2 exp (n)` integer (1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, ...)
   to define your enum. **Why ?** : Actually each active state of your
   enum will take a single bit of a 32 bits integer.
2. Add the [Flags](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.flagsattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute.

Then,

```
    [Flags] 
    public enum Status
    {
        S1 = 1,
        S2 = 2,
        S3 = 4,
        S4 = 8
    }
```

You can use [Enum.HasFlag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.enum.hasflag%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to check if a specific status is active :

```
public void DoWork(Status s) 
{
    var statusResult = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Status)).Where(v => s.HasFlag(v)).ToArray() ; 

    // StatusResult should now contains {1, 2}
}
```

Comment: There is an `HasFlag` instead of using `&` starting with .NET 4.0

Comment: Enum.GetValues returns an Array. The linq Where can't infer the types from usage, so a cast is required.

`var statusResult = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Status)).Cast<Status>().Where(v => s.HasFlag(v)).ToArray();`

Answer (score 3):

Declare your parameters with the params tag, then you get an array of enums:

```
public void DoWork (params Status[] args) {
    Console.WriteLine(args.Length);
}
```

Then you just pass them in as regular parameters:

```
DoWork(Status.S1, Status.S2);
```

This doesn't require changes to your enums, and easily copes with additional values. The flags solution above may work for you as well - depends on your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the Integer values of your enums that you want you can use this :

```
//declare your enum as byte
public enum Status : byte
{...}
**EDITED**
//then cast it to int to use the value
DoWork((int)Status.S1 , (int)Status.S2);
//change doWork to accept int[]
public void DoWork (params int[] args)
```

Comment: @Kerezo code edited , sorry i didn't realized that '|' would add param1 to param 2