# Can enum parameter be optional in c#?

Tags: c#, enums, optional-parameters

I've used [this helpful post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030090/how-do-you-pass-multiple-enum-values-in-c) to learn how to pass a list of Enum values as a parameter.

Now I would like to know whether I can make this parameter optional?

Example:

```
   public enum EnumColors
    {
        [Flags]
        Red = 1,
        Green = 2,
        Blue = 4,
        Black = 8
    }
```

I want to call my function that receives the Enum param like this:

```
DoSomethingWithColors(EnumColors.Red | EnumColors.Blue)
```

OR

```
DoSomethingWithColors()
```

My function should then look like what?

```
public void DoSomethingWithColors(EnumColors someColors = ??)
 {
  ...
  }
```

Comment: As an aside, practically every `enum` should have *some* defined value for `0`, and usually for `Flags` it should be called `None`.

Comment: The `[Flags]` attribute belongs on the `enum`, not an enum field.

Comment: If the value `default(EnumColors)` is the value he wants when the optional argument is omitted, he can use `public void DoSomethingWithColors(EnumColors someColors = 0)` or `public void DoSomethingWithColors(EnumColors someColors = default(EnumColors))`. Or like @Damien_The_Unbeliever said, intrduce `None=0,` in the enum type, and use `public void DoSomethingWithColors(EnumColors someColors = EnumColors.None)`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes it can be optional.

```
[Flags]
public enum Flags
{
    F1 = 1,
    F2 = 2
}

public  void Func(Flags f = (Flags.F1 | Flags.F2)) {
    // body
}
```

You can then call your function with or without parameter. If you call it without any parameter you'll get `(Flags.F1 | Flags.F2)` as the default value passed to the `f` parameter

If you don't want to have a default value but the parameter to be still optional you can do

```
public  void Func(Flags? f = null) {
    if (f.HasValue) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - all comments are valuable. Sadly only 1 can be accepted and typically the first 1 gets the nod.

Answer (score 6):

An `enum` is a value type, so you could use a nullable value type `EnumColors?`...

```
void DoSomethingWithColors(EnumColors? colors = null)
{
    if (colors != null) { Console.WriteLine(colors.Value); }
}
```

and then set the default value of `EnumColors?` to `null`

Another solution is to set `EnumColors` to an unused value...

```
void DoSomethingWithColors(EnumColors colors = (EnumColors)int.MinValue)
{
    if (colors != (EnumColors)int.MinValue) { Console.WriteLine(colors); }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Following code is perfectly valid:

```
void colorfunc(EnumColors color = (EnumColors.Red | EnumColors.Blue))
{
    //whatever        
}
```

calling it can be done like this:

```
colorfunc();
colorfunc(EnumColors.Blue);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can overload your function, so write two functions :

```
void DoSomethingWithColors(EnumColors colors)
{
    //DoWork
}

void DoSomethingWithColors()
{
    //Do another Work, or call DoSomethingWithColors(DefaultEnum)
}
```

Comment: You have a call from 2009 (?), they asked to tell you that there is.

Comment: Since [C# version 4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_4.0) from 2010, C# does have [optional parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx).

Comment: First : I work in VS2008, and VB.Net have optional parameter, and not C#, that's why i think that. So i've update my answer.
Second : My way is more clean (for me), and compatible with previous version.